# Stymied by ASP.NET Compilation Error CS0009

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll, compiler-errors

I'm getting error below when I debug my ASP.NET MVC app.

Any thoughts on how I could solve this?

Any idea how the problem would have occurred in the first place? I promise you I didn't go randomly deleting dll's from deep within protected directories on my system.

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error  Description: An
>   error occurred during the compilation
>   of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following
>   specific error details and modify your
>   source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0009:
>   Metadata file
>   'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'
>   could not be opened -- 'Error
>   importing module
>   'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'
>   of assembly
>   'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'
>   -- The system cannot find the file specified. '

Comment: Something's out of whack. Have you tried reinstalling .net framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed to fix it:

Add/Remove Programs -> .NET Framework 3.5SP1 -> Repair