# Run MVC4 Web App error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-8, iis-8

I'm getting this error when loading my web application:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll' could not be opened -- 'No metadata was found.'

Source Error:


[No relevant source lines]

Source File:    Line: 0
```

I'm getting pretty much the same error when I go to ASP.NET Configuration > Security :

```
    There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid 
server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the 
role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page 
where you can choose a new data store. 

    The following message may help in diagnosing the problem:
 (0): error CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\
v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll' could not be opened -- 'No metadata was found.'
```

Is there any solution to this issue?

I'm using :

- Visual studio 2012
- iis 8 express
- Windows 8 Pro 64bit

Running an MVC3 web app worked successfully.

Comment: Do you have Framework 4.5 and MVC4 installed on server?

Comment: These are installed by default with vs2012.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011134/stymied-by-asp-net-compilation-error-cs0009

Please refer this thread,might help you out.

Comment: I can't repair .net framework 4.5 because it's part of the operating system. I'm trying to repair the whole VS2012 now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After repairing VS2012, MVC4 Web Applications seemed to work again. Thanks everyone for your effort.